# Event Listener in AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, event-listener

I want to add an event listener to my AngularJS app.
The goal is to shorten any list in the app that has the class 'ui-list__list--shorten'.

I'm not sure what is best practice regarding this kind of usage of event listeners in AngularJS so I would like some tips about it.

Where do I implement this in an AngularJS (1) app?

Thanks in advance!

*An example of the code:*

```
var listUl = document.querySelectorAll('.ui-list__list--shorten');

// Add / Remove class 'list--shortened'
function listClass(list) {
  if (list.classList.contains("ui-list__list--shortened")) {
    list.classList.remove("ui-list__list--shortened");
  } else {
    list.classList.add("ui-list__list--shortened");
  }
}

// Shorten list & add show all button
function listShorten(list) {
  // Shorten the list
  listClass(list);

  // Creating elements
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  var span = document.createElement("span");
  var spanContent = document.createTextNode("Show all");

  // Adding classes
  span.classList.add("ui-list__button", "ui-list__button--closed");
  div.classList.add("ui-list__hide-overflow");

  span.appendChild(spanContent);
  div.appendChild(span);

  // Add after the list
  function insertAfter(list, div) {
    list.parentNode.insertBefore(div, list.nextSibling);
  }
  insertAfter(list, div);
}

// .ui-list__list longer than 100 px will be collapsed 
for (var i = 0; i < listUl.length; i++) {
  if (listUl[i].offsetHeight > 100) {
    listShorten(listUl[i]);
  }
}

// Change button when clicked
var listButton = document.querySelectorAll('.ui-list__button');

function changeButton(e) {
  if (e.classList.contains("ui-list__button--closed")) {
    e.innerHTML = "Show less";
    e.classList.remove("ui-list__button--closed");
    e.classList.add("ui-list__button--open");
  } else if (e.classList.contains("ui-list__button--open")) {
    e.innerHTML = "Show all";
    e.classList.remove("ui-list__button--open");
    e.classList.add("ui-list__button--closed");
  }
}

// Event listener for each button
for (i = 0; i < listButton.length; i++) {
  listButton[i].addEventListener("click", function () { listClass(this.parentNode.previousSibling); changeButton(this); });
}
```

Comment: Never manipulate directly DOM! You have to work on plain data, not DOM elements.

Comment: Okay thanks for the response! I'm not sure how I should handle this then though... Can you point me in a direction on how i should do this?

Comment: In general with the AngularJS framework, DOM manipulation is done with core directives or [custom directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). Inside directives, DOM maniplulation is done with [jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angularjs-s-jqlite) methods. Event listeners are added with [`elem.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you create an attribute and put it on your html div/span it could. Check [out this link for event listeners in angularJs](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_events.asp). the main Problem with your app is that you are writing the HTML In the angularJs this is not how to do it.
The way to go about it is to put it in a `templateUrl: 'index.html'` or just `template` and you can add the HTML in the actual code